# What's the reccomended way to indicate the author of an svg file?

Tags: svg, attributes, metadata

I am developing a tool for writing svg files programmatically. I was wondering what was the conventional way to add an author to the file. I was using something like this:

```
<svg version="1.1"
   baseProfile="full" width="297mm"
   height="210mm"
   viewBox="0 0 297 210"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   author="Bill Kill">
```

But I found also this convention using [DublinCore standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/metadata.html).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

  <title property="dc:title">Metamorphosis I-IV</title>
  <desc property="dc:creator">M.C. Escher</desc>

  <!-- graphical elements -->

</svg>
```

A little bit verbose. What's the recommended way?

Comment: The SVG specification is silent on that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of attributes recognized in the standard (see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg#Attributes)). If you add `author`, which is not among them, you will break that standard. Most browsers will not complain, but I think that using `desc` is safer. Also, it is the tag designed for your need.